# getting SIGABRT for UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to make a very simple iphone app that displays the real-time camera view of the device, and have added following codes that I found thru researching.

```
    -(void)viewDidLoad{
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

imagePicker.delegate = self;

imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];

[imagePicker release];
```

}

This only causes SIGABRT error, which I have no clue as to what to do with.

Since the above codes seem like a must to implement camera view, are there additional things that I have missed? Didn't think simply loading camera view would stress me...
Please help me out.

ps.I'm using xcode 4 btw.

Comment: Or could it be possibly because I'm building on iphone simulator rather than the actual device with the camera?

Comment: did you run it in real device? or simulator?

Comment: iOS Simulator doesn't have a camera. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this before adding

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

imagePicker.delegate = self;

imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];

[imagePicker release];

}

else
{
//.....
}
```